# Text over image in Framework7 grid

Tags: image, text, grid, overlay, html-framework-7

I have a series of images in a grid:

```
<div class="row home">
   <div class="col-20 ">
     <img class="icon" alt="icon" src="icon/blue.png" />
   </div>
  <div class="col-20">
    <img class="icon" alt="icon" src="icon/blue.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-20">
    <img class="icon" alt="icon" src="icon/blue.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-20">
     <img class="icon" alt="icon" src="icon/blue.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want overlay each image with some text (programmatically so not an image editing question). I've tried the various methods that Google suggests but nothing works.
Suggestions as to how to overlay the text will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) ?

Comment: Yes trued this but text is outride of the images...

Comment: This is usually CSS you need to be playing with, it should work if you do it right. If the text is outside of the images do a negative padding or margin to pull it back